# How to set a favicon.ico on a Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, favicon

I would like to know how to set a favicon.ico on a Heroku app.
Is there anyone who has done that and would have some advice on how to do it ?

I have made an attempt to place the *favicon.ico* file under the *public* folder or under an *assets* folder and using a line like:

```
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='/favicon.ico'>
```

or:

```
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}'>
```

in the HTML code; but without much success.

Comment: You're showing how you try to _link to_ your favicon, using some templating language. Are you sure the file itself is being served as a static asset? What technology are you using that you expect `{{ url_for(...) }}` to do anything?

Comment: I am not sure of anything, just trying to figure out how to make a favicon.ico appear on my app, using bits of information I can find on the net.

Comment: _Again_, what technology are you using to build your application? Python with Flask? Ruby on Rails? Laravel? Something else?

Comment: Node.js with express. If finally solved the problem. I will put my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case this could be useful to others.

Here is a method which worked for me to set a favicon on an Heroku app, using Node.JS and express.

1. Set a file named favicon.png (16x16, 32x32, 64x64 all work).
2. In the HTML head-block, after the line :
   <title>...</title> add this:

   <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png'/>